# Clear mappings in current buffer

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

How can I disable all user mappings only for current buffer in vim? I've tried `:mapclear` but it removed mappings for all buffers.

Comment: if there is a global mapping `xxx`, do you also need to have `xxx` disabled for the current buffer?

Comment: @LiuSha Yep, all mappings if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for `<buffer>` argument.

This argument ensures that the command or the mapping will be effective only in the local buffer rather than the global buffer.

To clear all the user-mapping in the local buffer, `:mapclear <buffer>` should be used.

For more information, look at `:h :map-<buffer>`

Comment: You might misunderstand my question. The `<buffer>` argument is for removing local buffer mappings, but what I want to do is remove all mappings temporarily for the current buffer.

Comment: @theJian.. I'm looking up for this as well and ended up here. have you solved this?

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan Unfortunately no, this snippet is the temporary solution I've used.
https://gist.github.com/theJian/beb8519127b9209f644197a09620d939

Answer (score 2):

Here is the temporary solution I've found so far.

```
let lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
let uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
let numbers = '0123456789'
let punctuation = "<>`@#~!\"$%^&/()=+*-_.,;:?\\\'{}[] " " and space
for str in [lowercase, uppercase, numbers, punctuation]
    for key in split(str, '\zs')
        execute printf("noremap <silent> <buffer> <nowait> %s :call DO_SOMETHING_OR_NOTHING<cr>", key)
    endfor
endfor
```

Basically this snippet will remap all the normal mappings for local buffer.

Comment: how about the `<f1>-<f12>` mappings

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be easily solved now if your vim version is >= 9.0, since you can get all the mappings through the `maplist()` function and set new mappings by calling the `mapset()` function. You just need to do some buffer-local mappings by remapping each previously mapped key sequence to itself.

```
for mapitem in maplist()
    call mapset(mapitem->extend(#{expr: 0, noremap: 1, rhs: mapitem.lhs, buffer: 1, silent: 1}))
endfor
```

The following script can also preserve the previously defined buffer-local mappings and will not overwrite them. If you are confused about the code, see `:h maplist()`, `:h mapset()`, `:h filter()`, `:h map()`, `:h lambda`, etc.

```
let bufmapsave = maplist()->filter('v:val.buffer == 1')
for mapitem in map(
    \ maplist()->filter('v:val.buffer == 0'),
    \ {_, val -> val->extend(#{expr: 0, noremap: 1, rhs: val.lhs, buffer: 1, silent: 1})})
    call mapset(mapitem)
endfor
for mapitem in bufmapsave
    call mapset(mapitem)
endfor
```

I've also worked out a solution for lower vim versions. We can use the `execute()` function (or the `:redir` command), which stringifies the output of a command. The mappings whose `attr` starts with `@`, `*@` or `&@` are buffer-local mappings (see `:h map-listing`). See `:h execute()`, `:h :redir`, `:h split()`, `:h :let-unpack`, `:h expr-=~`, `:h add()`, `:h index()`, etc. for more help.

```
let bufmapsave = []
let mapitems = []
for mapitem in split(execute('map | map!'), '\n\+')
    let [mapmode, lhs, attr; _] = split(mapitem, '\s\+', 1)
    if attr =~ '^[*&]\?@'
        call add(bufmapsave, lhs)
    else
        call add(mapitems, [mapmode, lhs])
    endif
endfor
for mapitem in mapitems
    let [mapmode, lhs] = mapitem
    if index(bufmapsave, lhs) == -1
        let mapcmd = mapmode == '!' ? 'noremap!' : (mapmode . 'noremap')
        silent exec mapcmd . ' <buffer> <silent> ' . lhs . ' ' . lhs
    endif
endfor
```